# How to set session in two different browser in same method with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have same method to save session with codeigniter. It's work in chrome but in firefox can't save session.

Comment: Reedit your question with your config.php session stuff but did you set you save path to something like example: `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/sessions/';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through below solutions and use depends on your needs.

if you are using filebase.

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/ci_sessions/';
```

If you store in database Then

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database'; // Change files to database
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; // This will be your database table for sessions
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

ci_session Table defination

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

**Please note:** If you are sharing same session with multiple domain than better to go with database storage.